# Einstein Solid Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter

[From The Oxford Solid State Basics by Steven H Simon]

(2.1) Einstein Solid

a) Classical Einstein ( or "Boltzmann") Solid:

Consider a three-dimensional simple harmonic oscillator with mass m and spring constant k (i.e., the mass is attached to the origin with the same spring constant in all three directions). The Hamiltonian is given in the usual way by 
$$ H = \frac {p^2}{2m} + \frac {k}{2} x^2$$
Calculate the classical partition function
$$Z= \int \frac {dp}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\int dx e^{-\beta H(p,x)}$$

Note: in this exercise p and x are three-dimensional vectors.

Using the partition function, calculate the heat capacity $3k_B$.

Conclude that if you can consider a solid to consist of N atoms all in harmonic wells, then the heat capacity should be $3Nk_B = 3R,$ in agreement with the law of Dulong and Petit.

I struggled to start this question as I was not sure how my initial approach ( and only approach) to differentiate H somehow to obtain infinitesimal p and x would work, but I was not sure how to even go about this as calculus is not a friend of mine. Since I was not able to attempt the first part I did not know how to approach the other parts to this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "infinitesimal $p$ and $x$".  Do you know generally how to evaluate integrals (in particular, the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral))?

Comment: What I meant by infinitesimal p and x is dp and dx. Whenever I have to evaluate Gaussian integrals I always use a standard table ( but it did not appear to me that Gaussian integrals had to be used here).

Comment: Here you integrate over $d^3\vec{p}$ and $d^3\vec{x}$ to be clear so each 3D integral gives a product of 3 1D integrals.

Comment: I'm still not following.  $x$ and $p$ are your integration variables, and $H$ is a quadratic function of $x$ and $p$.  If you plug $H$ into your expression for the partition function, do you not simply have six independent Gaussian integrals?